# Gulp объединить скрипты в папке

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

Есть небольшой таск, который объединяет все скрипты в один в файл. Как мне сделать так, чтобы он объединял файлы по папкам. Например в папке src/js лежат 2 папки **folder1** и **folder2**. Как на выходе получить 2 скрипта **folder1.js** и **folder2.js**, которые будут состоять из всех скриптов внутри них?

```
gulp.task('vendor-js', () => gulp
    .src('./src/js/**/*js' )
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/')
);
```

**Ответ**

Лучше использовать для таких целей `gulp-group-concat`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-group-concat

```
gulp.task('vendor-js', () => {
    const groupConcatConfig = readdirSync('./src/js/**/*js', {withFileTypes: true})
        .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
        .map(dirent => dirent.name)
        .reduce((acc, dirname) => {
            acc[`${dirname}.js`] = '**/lib/' + dirname + '/*.js';
            return acc;
        }, {});
return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*js')
    .pipe(groupConcat(groupConcatConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/'))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
.pipe(concat('vendor.js')
```

Используйте

```
groupConcat = require('gulp-group-concat');
...
.pipe(groupConcat('vendor.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Официальный рецепт от gulp-команды [тут](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md). Вот адаптированный код рецепта под ваше окружение:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var scriptsPath = 'src/js';

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
        });
}
gulp.task('vendor-js', function(done) {
   var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);
   if (folders.length === 0) return done(); // nothing to do!
   return folders.map(function(folder) {
      return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.js'))
        // concat into foldername.js
        .pipe(concat(folder + '.js'))
        // write to output
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
   });
});
```